# Currently targeted framework does not include System.Design. VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've tried to delete/remove the referenced assembly which is WindowsFormsIntegration.design, but it still does not work.

This is the error message:

> The currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" does not include "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which the referenced assembly "WindowsFormsIntegration.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" depends on. This caused the referenced assembly to not resolve. To fix this, either (1) change the targeted framework for this project, or (2) remove the referenced assembly from the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to the project options
2. Click on vertical tab *Compile*
3. Press the *Advanced Compile Options* button
4. Choose **.NET Framework 4** under *Target framework (all configurations)*

[image]

Comment: Answer solved the same issue when using Agilent Command Expert and scpi.net.